# Mapbox getDirections Error: value must be an object

Tags: react-native, mapbox, directions

I'm trying to add directions over a map in a React Native app.

I've followed this tutorial: https://blog.mapbox.com/adding-directions-to-the-react-native-store-locator-kit-ade759bd824e

The thing is that I'm receiving 'Error: value must be an object' when requesting the directions with `mbDirections.getDirections`. Does anyone knows the correct way to receive and store the directions?

Thanks!

Here's what I'm trying:

```
const Directions = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/directions');
const mbDirections = Directions({ accessToken: 'my token' });

async fetchDirections (origin, destination) {

const originLatLng = {
  latitude: origin[1],
  longitude: origin[0],
};

const destLatLng = {
  latitude: destination[1],
  longitude: destination[0],
};

const requestOptions = {
  geometry: 'polyline',
};

let res = null;
try {
  res = await mbDirections.getDirections([
    originLatLng,
    destLatLng,
  ], requestOptions);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

if (res !== null) {
  const directions = res.entity.routes[0];
  this.setState({ directions: directions });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this and let me know

```
try {
  res = await mbDirections.getDirections([
      { latitude: origin[1], longitude: origin[0]},
      { latitude: destination[1], longitude: destination[0]},
    ], {  geometry: 'polyline'});
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Same thing, man, the error persists. It looks like the problem is the variable 'res' receiving the response from the request.

Comment: @ThiagoResende wich version of Mapbox do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.4.1" and
    "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "^6.1.3"

Comment: try to uninstall that version... and run `npm i --save @mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl@6.0.2`